# Miller Rabin primality accuracy

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

I have been reading about the Miller-Rabin primality test. So far I think I got it except the part where the accuracy is stated.
E.g from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Accuracy)

> The error made by the primality test is measured by the probability
> for a composite number to be declared probably prime. The more bases a
> are tried, the better the accuracy of the test. It can be shown that
> if n is composite, then at most 1⁄4 of the bases a are strong liars
> for n. As a consequence, if n is composite then running k
> iterations of the Miller–Rabin test will declare n probably prime with
> a probability at most $4^{−k}$.

So if I understand correctly if we have a large number $N$ and if we have $k$ random witnesses then if none of them observes the non-primality of $N$, then the probability that $N$ is **not** a prime is $1$ in $4^k$

What I am not clear is where does this $\frac{1}{4}$ come from.
I understand we have $4$ conditions to be met (in order) i.e.:

1. $a \not\equiv 0 \mod N$
2. $a^{N-1} \not\equiv 1 \mod N$
3. $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod N$
4. $x \equiv \pm 1 \mod N$

The process is the following:
In the above $a$ is the witness. We first check condition (1).
If that passes we check condition (2).
Do do that we start multiplying $a, a \cdot a, a\cdot a\cdot a ....$ until we calculate $a^{N-1}$.
Do do that efficiently we can use the squaring method. If in the process of the multiplication during squaring we encounter a number e.g. $x$ such that the $x^2 \equiv 1$ but $x \not\equiv 1$ and $x \not\equiv -1$. (E.g $19^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {40}$ but $19 \not \equiv 1 \pmod {40}$ and $19 \not \equiv -1 \pmod {40}$) then the conditions (3) and (4) fails otherwise we proceed multiplying.
We check the final product for condition (2)

Does the $1/4$ mean that at most $1$ of these can be indicate a prime? If so, how is that validated?

Comment: Your four conditions are NOT the Miller-Rabin test!  They look like a weak form of the Solovay-Strassen test. For the Miller-Rabin test, write $N - 1 = 2^sd$ for $s \geq 1$ and odd $d$, and compute $a^d, a^{2d}, \ldots, a^{2^{s-1}d} \bmod N$.  Read the test on the Wikipedia page. It *is* technical and complicated, no way around that. Anyway, the "1/4" is not from anything like "4 conditions".  It is from what you wrote: for odd composite $N > 1$, at most 1⁄4 of the bases $a$ in $\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$ are strong liars for $N$.  It is *hard* to prove that. Do you know what "strong liar" means?

Comment: @KCd: They seem to me the same as the reference of davidlowryduda. What is the difference. No I don't really know what strong liar is? Is it another name for Carmichael numbers?

Comment: I think under some assumption the algorithm becomes deterministic if you let $a$ runs from $2$ to $\ln^2 N$

Comment: @Ahmad: I didn't understand that statement but these conditions are meant to be separate evaluations per witness.

Comment: A strong liar is *not* a Carmichael number.  You list of $4$ conditions is confusing because you don't say what "$x$" means.  Read the Miller-Rabin test in references other than Wikipedia until you find a description of the test that you can understand. It might help to carry out the test in a few actual  examples to see what is going on (what strong liars really are).

Comment: @KCd: $a$ is the witness. $x$ is a number during the multiplication process of $a$ that the $x^2 \equiv 1$ but $x \not \equiv 1$ and $x \not \equiv -1$. Does this clear things in my post?

Comment: Under Extended Riemann hypothesis the Miller-Rabin test becomes deterministic if you test it with $a$ running from $2$ to $\ln^2 N$ meaning its guarantees to give you a correct answer in polynomial time, i know its off topic since you are talking about the probabilistic version.

Comment: @Ahmad: I didn't know there were two versions. Perhaps that is the reason that in the answer there is a different condition?

Comment: @Jim yes, that makes your conditions clearer, but you should *really* update your post to say what $x$ means!  Concerning Ahmad's comment about Miller-Rabin having a deterministic form, the correct range that is provably sufficient under the Generalized (or "Extended") Riemann Hypothesis is from $2$ to $2(\log N)^2$, *not* from $2$ to $(\log N)^2$.  Miller proved the upper bound under a Riemann Hypothesis is $O((\log N)^2)$ but he could not determine an explicit $O$-constant.  Bach later showed the $O$-constant could be taken as $2$.

Comment: @KCd: I updated the post. Is it clear now?

Comment: Well, “the multiplication process of $a$” in your post is vague. Why not spell out exactly what the relevant sequence of powers of $a$ is so that the question is more self-contained? No account of the Miller-Rabin test elsewhere is obscure in that way about what is computed during the test.

Comment: @KCd: I updated the post. Is that better?

Comment: The powers are *not* all of $a$, $a^2$, $a^3$, and so on up to $a^{N-1}$. I already indicated in my first comment what the actual powers of $a$ are.  This will be my final comment about your post.

Comment: For $N - 1$, I used binary representation, and to calculate $a^{N-1}$ I consider pingala's algorithm which is essentially a squaring method. E.g. for $N - 1 = 90 = 64+16+8+2$ so if it would be $a^{90} = a^{64}\cdot a^{16}\cdot a^8 \cdot a^2$So each of the powers of $a$ have indeed as exponent $2e$ but I think the way I phrase it and my terminology is confusing to others. I am sorry for that.

Comment: You don’t use a=1 or a=N-1, because every odd composite N will pass. And you don’t check if a= 0 mod N because you only take 2 <= a <= N-2 in the first place.

Comment: Jim, the whole point of Miller-Rabin ist that you calculate a^90 as a^45, squared. So you can use the fact that x^2 mod prime is 1 only if x=+/- 1, and for example for N=15 the fact that 4^2 = 1 mod N proves that N must be composite.

Answer (score 1):

A more rigorous statement is as follows.

Suppose we want to consider whether $n$ is prime. Let $W_n(b)$ be the statement that

1. $1 \leq b < n$,
2. - $b^{n-1} \not \equiv 1 \bmod n$, or
   - there is some $i$ with $2^i \mid (n-1)$ and $1 < \gcd(b^{(n-1)/2^i} - 1, n) < n.$

If $W_n(b)$, then we say that $b$ is a witness to the compositeness of $n$. Then Rabin proved that no more than $1/4$ of the numbers $1 \leq b < n$ are *not* witnesses of compositeness. (This is Theorem 1 of his paper, full citation below).

Thus if you independently randomly choose $k$ distinct bases mod $n$, then each will pass Miller's test with probability bounded above by $1/4$. This is where the $1/4^k$ comes from.

I'll note that typically, the number is actually much less than $1/4$.

---

### References

Rabin, Michael O. (1980), "Probabilistic algorithm for testing primality", Journal of Number Theory, 12 (1): 128–138,

Comment: So basically that $1/4$ is something we take for granted because Rabin proved it? Because that was my original question. Is it a proof I can read somewhere?

Comment: Are the conditions you mentioned different than mine in my post?

Comment: This paper is freely available online from the publisher. And the conditions I mention are not the same as what you mention.

Comment: What is the difference? In my post $a$ is what you denote as $b$ i.e. the witness and I am using the root of one property. I.e.  $x$ is a number during the multiplication process of $a$ that the $x^2 \equiv 1$ but $x \not \equiv 1$ and $x \not \equiv -1$. So I think only the last bullet of point (2) is different. What is the name of that property?

Comment: My description of the post is from a book. There is no mention there of that second bullet: `there is some  with....` but I also see that in the Rabin paper you linked. Is that some way for the book to make the topic more "digestible"?

Comment: I think it has been proven that for n < 2^64, every composite number will be _proven_ composite by one of the 12 smallest primes as a witness. Proven by a combination of cleverness and tons of brute force. This is better than you would expect from the 1/4 probability (which would mean with 32 random witnesses we expect one composite number to slip through the net) and the log log n proven bound would require 4,096 tests.

Comment: @gnasher729: What is the name of that algorithm/approach?

Comment: Found it through Google. Lots of information which sets of witnesses work for how many numbers, and one paper.

Answer (score 1):

“So if I understand correctly if we have a large number N and if we have k random witnesses then if none of them observes the non-primality of N, then the probability that N is not a prime is 1 in 4^k”

No, that’s the probability that a composite N passes k tests. Miller-Rabin only works for odd N. If you pick a random large odd N, then the probability that it is prime is 2/log N. After k tests, the probability is 2/log N that N is prime, 1 - 2/log N that it is composite, and less than 1 / 4^k that it is a composite number passing k tests. If it passes k tests, the probability that N is composite is less than log N / 2 4^k. For example a 100 digit odd number passing 3 tests is still more likely to be composite.

Comment: Where is that $2/log N$ coming from? Also is that $logN/{24}^k$?

Comment: N is prime with probability 1/log n. Odd n the probability is 2/log n because n is not divisible by 2.

Comment: @gnasher729 How did you get logN/(2*4^k) as probability? I'm trying to figure it out using Bayes theorem but couldn't find it.